# Get NSDictionary Selected row in Push for Segue [IOS]

Tags: ios, dictionary

Hey guys I have an array of dictionaries plist file that I am reading from. I am using a Push for Segue method to pass on my data(a dictionary) to the next view controller. How can I get the selected row using a dictionary? I am making a table view app and I have already nade the (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath and it works.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
NSDictionary *d = [self.model.players objectAtIndex:0]
nextVC.title = [d valueForKey:@"Player"]
nextVC.info = d
}
```

When I use the above code and use the ObjectAtIndex:0 and specify 0 I can extract the data for that specific player in the next view controller. But I want to get the correct one based on the user selected row. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[self.model.players objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]];

should do it

Comment: when I do that it gives a warning saying incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending *NSindexPath *' to parameter of type NSUInteger (aka unsigned int). Any Idea how to fix that?

Comment: Yes, my bad. Say int row = [[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row]; then use that int for object at index

Comment: thanks, that solved my problem. I really appreciate the quick response and thanks again.